# Override Windows environment variable value?

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, user-profile

I want to permanently change the value of the "Username" variable of Windows to fix a problem of my Windows 8 with the user profile folder name.

I've tried  to set a new environment variable using SETX tool like this:

```
SETX /M Username "value"
```

...The new variable is generated, I can see it in the registry with the other variables, but is not overrided 'cause if I try to display the value of Username variable the it displays the old value.

Is it possibly to do what I want?

Comment: Have you changed the user name in control panel?  The folder name doesn't change but %username% will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMD` reads the system environment variables when it starts. To re-read those variables you need to restart `CMD`.

As for the variable `%USERNAME%`: that variable is automatically populated with the username of the currently logged-in user. You'd have to change the username to change the value of that variable. Don't tamper with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Maybe I should have said this but if I have come to this point I think it was obvious to assume that I've already tried the more basic things such as restarting CMD and restarting the PC to see if the changes effect emerged. Please you can try to set the "Username" variable to see that does not happens anything and the value don't change.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you were talking about the `%USERNAME%` environment variable. You can't change the variable that way, because it's automatically populated with the username of the currently logged-in user. To change the value of that variable, you'll have to change the username. Same goes for e.g. the variable `%COMPUTERNAME%`. Don't tamper with these variables.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain what you consider wrong about this answer?

Comment: Don't worry, probably it was a troll or just a person with totally absence of reasonament and judgement. This is the main problem of "free moderators" and vote systems where all users with low reputation can vote what he wants to...

Comment: I'm not worried, just interested.