# Problem to change environment variables together with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, gdal, processbuilder

I'm trying to use ProcessBuilder to run an exeprogram which connects to a database.
Defaut environment variable is for USERNAME in my windows configuration is "PAUL", but the user that shall connect to the database should be "postgres".

I can run this command in a "command window" in Windows 10:
C:\Program Files\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" c:\Temp\mydata.shp PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" "mytable"

In java I'm trying this:

```
Public void exec(){
    command = new String[] {C:\\Program Files\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe", 
    "-f", "\"ESRI Shapefile\"", 
    "C:\\Temp\\mydata.shp", 
    "PG:\"host="127.0.0.1 user=postgres dbname=mydbname password=mypassword\"",
    "\"mytable\""};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.environment().remove("USERNAME");
    pb.environment().put("USERNAME", "postgres");
            
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader bufIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String str1 = null;
    while ((str1= bufIn.readLine()) != null) {
        textOutput.append(str1 + "\n");
        System.out.println(str1 + "\n");
    }
}
```

When I debug and check the environment variables for ProcessBulider pb, before pb.start() I can see that USERNAME=postgres

The output I get is:
ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
FATAL:  role "PAUL" don't exist

Would be grateful if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Kind regards,
Paul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Windows environment variable value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777046/override-windows-environment-variable-value)

Answer (score 0):

according to

[Override Windows environment variable value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777046/override-windows-environment-variable-value)

USERNAME can't be so easily overwritten...

your code is fine but USERNAME is somehow special on windows, otherwise you could run you applications with any user on you system

Comment: Thanks Bernd Farka for answering.So if I understand you correctly I can't execute ogr2ogr with a java progressBuilder if the login username is different from the postgreSQL user name... But when I run the command in a "command window" then USERNAME = PAUL and it works. Some how I think it must be possible to run the ogr2ogr from java.

Comment: no, you simply can't change that variable... what looks strange to me: you are passing a username via your args, why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

If I use Process instead:
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", c:\PROGRA~1\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\Temp\mydata.shp "" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres password=mypassword dbname=mydbname" "mytable"});

It worked well!!! But I had to use the shortname for path: C:\Program Files, which wasn't necessary when using ProcessBuilder....
I wonder what the differense is?